# How to create marketing cloud account

Tags: marketing-cloud, account, businessprocess

How to create marketing cloud account like salesforce developer edition .if is it possible ?. could you please send me for creating marketing cloud account links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible for a short time but isn’t anymore. If you are a marketing cloud partner, you can have a partner account provisioned with limited functionality (eg mobile connect , you will have to pay for this at a subsidised rate)

Comment: Hi  @Data_Kid
is there any possible way to create markeitng cloud account.