# Does marketing cloud provide free testing org as Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am starting to learn Marketing Cloud and I would like as first thing to integrate it with Salesforce. Does Marketing Cloud provide a free org for developers as Salesforce does? If yes, where can I get it?

Comment: Thank you @JohannesSchapdick, the last answer to that question is older than 2 years...how could I ask for an update answer?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208266/how-to-create-marketing-cloud-account thats one year ago. There are still several questions in that matter. You might (if you are allowed) just create a comment under those specific answers.

Comment: The answers are still valid. There is no Dev version. SFMC offered it for a very short period of time, then ended the option. They also have discontinued most of those dev accounts that they set up during that time period. Your only option is inside of a live, purchased version of MC.

Comment: thanks @Gortonington, IMO this is very inconvient and I hope they will fix it soon

Comment: Agreed, but I don't see it being changed anytime in the near future.